# How to assert two variables are equal when the implementation of PartialEq isn't appropriate?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, traits

In my program, I represent "events" with the following structure:

```rust
struct Event {
    value: &'static str,
    timestamp: usize,
}
```

So far, I used `PartialEq` to compare `Event` variables: most of the time, I consider two `Event`s to be equal if their `value` is the same:

```rust
impl PartialEq for Event {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.value == other.value
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_loose_equality() {
        let a = Event { value: "a-value", timestamp: 12345 };
        let b = Event { value: "a-value", timestamp: 23456 };

        assert_eq!(a, b);
    }
}
```

However, in certain tests, I would like to ensure that two such variables are "strictly equals": The  test should fail they have different `timestamp` (are not the same in respect to `Eq`).

As per the documentation of `assert_eq!`:

> Asserts that two expressions are equal to each other (using PartialEq).
>   [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.assert_eq.html)

So, I am looking for an `Eq` equivalent, an `assert_Eq_eq!` in sort.

(or am I misunderstanding how `Eq` works and should be used?)

Here is what I fail to complete:

```rust
impl Eq for Event {}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_strict_equality() {
        let a = Event { value: "a-value", timestamp: 12345 };
        let b = Event { value: "a-value", timestamp: 12345 };

        // ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're swimming upstream fighting against the current. Go with the flow. Let `PartialEq` be strict equality and define a separate trait or method for loose equality.

```
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq)]
struct Event { .. }

impl Event {
    fn loose_eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.value == other.value
    }
}
```

```
#[test]
fn test_loose_equality() {
    let a = Event { value: "a-value", timestamp: 12345 };
    let b = Event { value: "a-value", timestamp: 23456 };

    assert!(a.loose_eq(b));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would create "views" of the type as appropriate:

```
struct Event {
    value: &'static str,
    timestamp: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Exact<'a> {
    value: &'a &'static str,
    timestamp: &'a usize,
}

impl Event {
    fn exact(&self) -> Exact<'_> {
        let Self { value, timestamp } = self;
        Exact { value, timestamp }
    }
}

fn demo(a: Event, b: Event) {
    assert_eq!(a.exact(), b.exact());
}
```

Here I've chosen to take references to each of the fields to demonstrate the general case, but you don't need references for this specific example (`&str` and `usize` implement `Copy` and are small).

You could also choose to not implement `PartialEq` on the original type at all, and *only* perform comparisons through views:

```rust
assert_eq!(a.exact(), b.exact());
assert_eq!(a.loose(), b.loose());
```

Comment: This is pretty ingenious.
Although I ended implementing a more "straightforward" solution (using [John 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61619631/how-to-assert-two-variables-are-equal-when-the-implementation-of-partialeq-isnt/61620048#61620264)) that seemed more adequate to my code.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the strict equality only in tests, and your struct only has two fields, I'd simply compare these fields directly:

```
let a = Event { value: "a-value", timestamp: 12345 };
let b = Event { value: "a-value", timestamp: 12345 };
assert_eq!(a.value, b.value);
assert_eq!(a.timestamp, b.timestamp);
```

This looks like the easiest and most readable option to me.

Comment: This is indeed the most "straightforward" way of tackling this issue.
However, it does not "scale" well if field are added to the structure, and add some noise to the tests (#fields assertions to verify one equality).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are misunderstanding something. `Eq` doesn't have any new methods over `PartialEq`. It's just an assertion that the implementation of `PartialEq` is reflexive (as well as the transitivity and symmetry assumed with `PartialEq`).

If you want to have a different "strict" equality, you could make your own trait (if you expect to use this a lot) or simply have a method `fn strict_eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool` attached to `Event`.

Given such a method you could write a macro to use that method.

The full source for `assert_eq!` can be found [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f8d394e5184fe3af761ea1e5ba73f993cfb36dfe/src/libcore/macros/mod.rs#L42-L75) and could be easily adapted, but a (perhaps overly) simple version would be something like

```
macro_rules! assert_strict_eq {
    ($left: expr, $right: expr) => {
        if !$left.strict_eq(&$right) {
            panic!(r#"assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `{:?}`,
 right: `{:?}`"#, $left, $right)
        }
    }
}
```

[(example usage)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e9ddb12e6c612e79403cf96e862862e)

Answer (score -1):

Unlike JavaScript, Rust does not support equal vs. strict equal.

However, you can achieve similar effect by implementing your own trait and macro:

```rust
pub trait StrictEq {
    fn strict_eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool;
}

macro_rules! assert_strict_eq {
    ($left:expr, $right:expr) => {{
        match (&$left, &$right) {
            (left_val, right_val) => {
                assert!(left_val.strict_eq(right_val));
            }
        }
    }};
}
```

The implementation for `Event` would be rather simple:

```rust
impl StrictEq for Event {
    fn strict_eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.value == other.value && self.timestamp == other.timestamp
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what this answer brings compared to the existing answers which suggest [using a custom trait and macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61620048/155423).

Comment: @Shepmaster I think the idea of implementing custom traits with custom macros is a very straight forward approach in this case, which will likely be recommended by many people. The main difference of this implementation is that this macro utilizes the default implementation of `assert!`, and it does not require `Event` struct derive `Debug` trait. The answer you mentioned would not compile if the struct does not derive `Debug` trait. Feel free to choose whichever based on your needs.